# Word or short description for someone who roams around in his local city and knows about local lesser known places, events, things to do etc

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, synonyms

Just like we use travellers or wanderlust or globe trotters etc for people who enjoy travelling out of their own city, I want a word for people who enjoy roaming about their own city and knowing local stuff, like rare book shops, non-crowded running trails, lesser known little cafés, small offbeat local events, etc.

Comment: @DManokhin -- "Travellers" and "travelling" are spelled correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have **explorer** or **discoverer**.

If you are finding *lesser known little cafés* or *small offbeat local events* then you are exploring.

Discoverer could also be used as you are discovering less well-known places/events.

Comment: @Ryan No problem. If the answer helped feel free to press the tick next to my answer to let others know that this answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

While "explorer" or "discoverer" certainly work, they're both kind of *vanilla* in that they lack the kind of romantic nuance that "wanderlust" has when describing someone who loves to travel.

There is no single word for this, but there are any number of possible expressions.  For example, we could focus on this person's love of discovery.

> She loves to **ferret out** some back-alley cafe or side-street bookstore known to only a cognizant few.

Or include something about their wandering habits:

> She's a kind of **peripatetic sleuth**, who knows all the best places in the city.

Or focus on their wisdom and the fruits of their knowledge:

> She's like a **guru** of all this city's **hidden gems**.

Answer (score 0):

There is also an old set phrase, *off the beaten track*, which refers to a little used path, trail, or road; the "beaten track" is one that has much traffic on it:

> He tended to avoid the beaten track.
>
> He looked for things off the beaten track.